# Error on creating CMS Key database file for IBM HTTP Web Server SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, csr, ibmhttpserver

I am getting below error when I select Key database type as CMS for creating a CSR for IBM HTTP Server-

The CMS Java Native Library was not found.Please make sure the SSL Component required by your product is installed and the library path is defined correctly.Consult your product documentation for further information.

Please help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: What release? What operating system? How do you invoke ikeyman?

Comment: OS is 64 bit AIX, IBM HTTP Server version 7.0 and I am invoking ikeyman from GUI. (/appdata/IBM/HTTPServer_V7/bin directory).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME is pointing to the IBM Java.

i.e.  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Java80

Comment: Hi hill, you means Java in http server directory(/appdata/IBM/HTTPServer_V7) in my case or the one in profile_root/java.